# Best way to store a date in a database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am creating a personal no frills app.. from which I have a need to store dates so I can call out form the database on any given month details for that month. However I have reoccuring needs and I am trying to figure out if its better to just keep appending more dates with month day year and more rows per or if its better to store a month/day along with a interval, or what?

Would it be better to store dates like

Just adding new rows per data forever til the end of time for each month

1. 2014-01-01
2. 2014-02-01
3. 2014-03-01

or would it be better to month | day | interval and calculate it somehow via PHP and query where I pull everything then caclulate it all on the now vs the interval

- 01 | 01 | 30
- 01 | 01 | 120

Comment: Can you post a layout of the two options?  It's a little unclear right what you're trying to do...

Comment: It's impossible to say with the information given. I'll guess that you don't want to store *dates*, but some records which, among other things, have a date. Then just store each record in a row with a date column, and filter and group and merge using SQL queries as necessary.

Comment: I always store dates as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 1/1/1970 (the unix epoch) - an integer. It makes querying for entries between any two times very quick and easy. It also affords you the most flexibility when formatting them for display. StackOverflow does the same thing, as evidenced by the way that posts appear as "x seconds ago", "x minutes ago" or _formatted_date_. You can get the number of seconds at the current moment with the `time()` function.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the MySQL datatype: **date**?

Comment: use date datatype to store the date Y-m-d format

Comment: I meant to say, Android phones use the same strategy for recording the arrival/outgoing times of calls and texts, albeit with a precision of milliseconds, rather than seconds.

Comment: @enh Those require timestamps more precise than `DATE`, so that's a logical choice. For just *dates* however (no time component), the native `DATE` type makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @deceze - good point. I'd overlooked that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd tend to store the individual dates in the table.

A couple of notes:

When someone sets up a recurring event, I'd store that in a separate table, with the "rules", (first sunday of the month, the 15th of the month on odd dated months, etc.) and spin through that to generate the calendar dates, to add to "event" table. I'd also require some user-specified end to recurrence (limited to something like a year, or five years, so I'm not spinning a boatload of future dates out.

In the [event] table, I'd store a foreign key back to the recurring series... a value in the FK column would indicate it was a "recurring" event, as well as tying the [event] row back to the specific recurrence series it was part of.

If someone changes or deletes a recurring event, I'd find the related rows in the [event] table, and do what was appropriate.

One advantage is that it would allow me to record information specific to each occurrence, as well as information about the recurring event.

Another advantage, if one occurrence of an event has to be cancelled, or postponed, I don't want to have to muck with changing the recurrence rule, I just mark that one [event] as cancelled or postponed.

Comment: Makes sense.. for some reason or another I just couldn't wrap my brain around which would be a batter scenario for use..

Comment: @chris: It really depends on the requirements, what you are trying to do. For notating some annually recurring calendar dates (for example, "Mom's Birthday", I'd implement a separate "rule" table, and not store individual event rows. (I'd spin through the event table, AND I'd spin through the "rule" table to generate rows, but not necessarily store those rows as an [event]; I'd just notate on the calendar the same way that Holidays are notated; not as a  scheduled "event" (with notes, place, time), but as just a notation on the entire day. Same way I'd notate "full moon" on the calendar.